# Swift: Create UILabel in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift, uilabel

I have a table view controller in which the following array is declared:

```
var newData = [String]()
```

In my viewDidLoad function, I have the following:

```
newData = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I'm trying to create a UILabel object inside of a table cell. So far, I have the following in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

//Programmatically create label
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(280.0, 14.0, 300.0, 30.0))
newLabel.tag = 1
newLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17.0)
newLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

cell.addSubview(newLabel)
cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) = newData[indexPath.row] //This is where I get the error
```

But, I get the following error: "Cannot assign to the result of this expression". In Objective-C, I have it written as:

```
[(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1] setText:[newData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

My question is: How do I write the preceding line of code in Swift? Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and proper way to assign text would be, when you create label assign text at that time

```
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(280.0, 14.0, 300.0, 30.0))
newLabel.text = newData[indexPath.row]
newLabel.tag = 1
```

### Swift 3

```
var newLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 280.0, y: 14.0, width: 300.0, height: 30.0))
newLabel.text = newData[indexPath.row]
newLabel.tag = 1
```

## Edit

Even if you want to use viewWithTag method then you have to use it in this way by typecasting

```
var lbl : UILabel? = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
lbl?.text = newData[indexPath.row]
```